# SwiftPM Library not being included

Tags: swift, package, swift-package-manager

I am currently trying to create a Swift Wrapper for a C Library. To do so I am using the Swift Package manager.

My plan was to create a `system-module` first which wraps the wanted C-Library. After that this Library would be included in another Swift package of type `Library`. To test everything out I wanted to make another Swift package of type `executable`

The problem lies in the last part. The executable does not find the references to the `Library`.

To explain everything better, here is my workflow:

**1)**
Create a new swift package with: `swift package init --type system-module`.
Here is the final `Package.swift` file:

```
// swift-tools-version:4.2

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "Clibmongoc",
    pkgConfig: "libmongoc-1.0",
    providers: [
        .brew(["mongo-c-driver"])
    ],
    products: [
        .library(name: "Clibmongoc", targets: ["Clibmongoc"])
    ]
)
```

And the `.modulemap`:

```
module Clibmongoc [system] {
    header "/usr/local/include/libmongoc-1.0/mongoc.h"
    link "Clibmongoc"
    export *
}
```

**2)**
Now I had to create the `Library`:

First I initialized it with: `swift package init --type Library`. The resulting Package.swift was:

```
// swift-tools-version:4.2

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "SwiftLibMongoC",
    products: [
        // Products define the executables and libraries produced by a package, and make them visible to other packages.
        .library(
            name: "SwiftLibMongoC",
            targets: ["SwiftLibMongoC"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        // Dependencies declare other packages that this package depends on.
        .package(url: "../Clibmongoc", from: "1.0.2")
    ],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages which this package depends on.
        .target(
            name: "SwiftLibMongoC",
            dependencies: ["Clibmongoc"]),
        .testTarget(
            name: "SwiftLibMongoCTests",
            dependencies: ["SwiftLibMongoC"]),
    ]
)
```

So basically I just copied the newly created package from before into the new Library. I also made sure the git tag of the `system-module` was set to `1.0.2`. I also made sure to include the dependency in the target. As expected when creating the `.xcodeproj` I had access to the `Clibmongoc` `system-module`.

Now we arrive to the problem.

**3)** I created the test module with `swift package init --type executable` and I included the newly created `Library` into the manifest:

```
// swift-tools-version:4.2

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "SwiftLibMongoCTest",
    dependencies: [
        // Dependencies declare other packages that this package depends on.
        .package(url: "../SwiftLibMongoC", from: "0.0.2")
    ],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages which this package depends on.
        .target(
            name: "SwiftLibMongoCTest",
            dependencies: ["SwiftLibMongoC"]),
        .testTarget(
            name: "SwiftLibMongoCTestTests",
            dependencies: ["SwiftLibMongoCTest"]),
    ]
)
```

Again I made sure the version from the git tag is set properly to `0.0.2` and also the dependency `SwiftLibMongoC` has been set to the dependency in the target.

When trying to build the executable it works, however when the `.xcodeproj` is being created, I can import the `system-module` `Clibmongoc` but I do not get the `auto completion` for the new `Library` `SwiftLibMongoC`. But if I import it and build it i do not get errors however, if I try to access the default generated code from a `Library` in the new `executable` I get an error:

> use of unresolved identifier

Any aid is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This was actually quite a stupid mistake. The default access level for swift is internal, meaning you can not see the code from outside of the module. I never really looked at the pre-generated code and therefore I never imagined I had to change the default struct to public.

I hope in the future this gets addressed better in the docs.